# async function with the class in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I have create a class in nodejs

```
class ApnService {
  sendNotification(deviceType, deviceToken, msg, type, id) {
    try {
      const note = await apnProvider.send(note, deviceToken)
      console.log(note)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
}

export default ApnService
```

What I need to do is to convert above function to `async`. But when I use below syntax It throws me error

```
SyntaxError: src/services/apn.js: Unexpected token (43:19)
  41 |   }
  42 | 
> 43 |   sendNotification = async(deviceType, deviceToken, msg, type, id) => {
     | 

               ^
```

Below is the syntax

```
class ApnService {
  sendNotification = async(deviceType, deviceToken, msg, type, id) => {
    try {
      const note = await apnProvider.send(note, deviceToken)
      console.log(note)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
}

export default ApnService
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can simply add async before function name to declare that function as async,

```
class ApnService {
  async sendNotification(deviceType, deviceToken, msg, type, id) {
    try {
      const note = await apnProvider.send(note, deviceToken)
      console.log(note)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
}

export default ApnService
```

Comment: Yes this will work but this is not ES-7 syntax. Am I right?

Comment: @DarkKnight Async functions are introduced in ES2017. If you are using es6 then you need to compile it using babel or webpack

Comment: This is my `.babelrc` `{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "node": 4.3
      }
    }]
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["istanbul"]
    }
  }
}
` Could you please let me know what I am missing here?

Comment: Can you tell more about version of ecmascript and Node that you are using currently ?

Comment: node version `v8.9.3` and How do I check this `version of ecmascript`?

Comment: Have you tried above syntax ? you still have any errors ?

Comment: Above syntax works for me. But I know this is not the latest es7 syntax

Comment: If you want to know that which latest ecmascript features your current node version support than have a look at this [website](https://node.green/#ES2017-features-async-functions)

Comment: `async arrow functions` this should works as listed the link. Ok now I am asking a new question related to this. THanks for the help!!!

Comment: what happens when you actually create at instance of this Class and try to call async method of this class? how would you 'await' for the result of this call?

Answer (score 3):

`async` is a keyword to designate an asynchronous function, try

```
class ApnService {
    async sendNotification(deviceType, deviceToken, msg, type, id) { 
        try { 
            const note = await apnProvider.send(note, deviceToken) 
            console.log(note) 
        } catch (err) { 
            console.log(err) 
        } 
    }
 }
export default ApnService;
```

Comment: OP isn't trying to use `async` as a function, they're using it as a keyword. Look again: `sendNotification = async (/* args */) => {`

Comment: Ah yes, narrow mobile screen.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Foo {
    x = something
}
```

This assignment is an example of a class field. The usage of [class property / class field](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) syntax is currently at stage-3 in the TC39 process, meaning it is not yet in ECMAScript and not yet supported natively by all JS engines. It can be used via transpilers like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties), but only if you configure and run such a transpiler yourself.

Luckily you don't need class field syntax to make a class method async, you can just use the `async` keyword.

```
class Foo {
    async myMethod () {/* ... */}
}
```

Comment: This is my `.babelrc` `{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "node": 4.3
      }
    }]
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["istanbul"]
    }
  }
}
` Could you please let me know what I am missing here?