# Calling `bind()` on an async function partially works

Tags: javascript, node.js, bind

I'm calling `.bind(this)` on an async function defined in another module inside of a class constructor.

The class is as below

```
class CannedItem {
  constructor (config) {
    ...
    this._fetch = config.fetch.bind(this)
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

The function is something like

```
module.exports = [
   {
      ...
      fetch: async () => {
        // Want to refer to 'this' bound to the CannedItem object here
      }
   }
]
```

However when the function is called, `this` is bound to an empty object.

Confusingly Visual Studio Code debugger has the object in scope bound as `this` in the debugger window, see attached screenshot, however inspecting the variable in the console lists it as undefined. This looks to me like there is a bug. Is this the case or am I misusing `.bind()`?

The only thing that seems a little unusual is the async function. I tried searching for issues with async and `.bind()` but no dice.

I am running NodeJs 8.11.1 and the latest VSCode (1.30.2)

[image: Screenshot showing the discrepancy between debugger and output]

Comment: The question was actually about use of async, not about binding of arrow function, so reference to duplicate is not useful. The question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53313507/async-function-with-the-class-in-javascript Is more relevant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't rebind arrow functions because `this` is fixed to the lexically defined `this`. You need a regular function if you plan on using `bind()` or any of its relatives:

```js
class CannedItem {
  constructor(config) {
    this.myname = "Mark"
    this._fetch = config.fetch.bind(this)
  }
}

let obj = {
  fetch: async() => { // won't work
    return this.myname
    // Want to refer to 'this' bound to the CannedItem object here
  }
}

let obj2 = {
  async fetch() {     // works
    return this.myname
    // Want to refer to 'this' bound to the CannedItem object here
  }
}

// pass arrow function object
let c1 = new CannedItem(obj)
c1._fetch().then(console.log)  // undefined 

// pass regular function object
let c2 = new CannedItem(obj2)
c2._fetch().then(console.log)  // Mark
```

As a bonus, if you use a regular function, you might not need `bind()`.

```
 this._fetch = config.fetch
```

will work if you call it from the instance.

Comment: So the fact the debugger shows the value bound to `CannedItem` as I would expect is a red-herring? It basically shouldn't show that?

Comment: In your debugger code it looks like `fetch` is directly on the object where the lexical `this` is the correct value.